# ChartJS Scatter plot cuts highest and lowest points in half

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

When plotting a time scatter plot by category (x-axis = time, y-axis = category) the points at the top and the bottom of the graph get cut in half:
[image: screenshot]
Is there are way to solve this problem?
I use ChartJS with Angular 6 and the ng2-charts wrapper. This is my Options Object:

```js
  public scatterChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour',
          min: this.minDate.toISOString(),
          max: this.maxDate.toISOString()
        },
        display: true,
        ticks:{
          padding: 50
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        type: 'category',
        gridLines: {
          display:true,
        },

      }],
    }
  };
```

Comment: It looks like your max date is the highest value on the chart, which also sets the limit of the y-axis.  Can you just add more time onto your y-axis, so your max value is actually something like `max: new Date(this.maxDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24).toISOString()` ? The multiplication at the end should add one day's time to your max date value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but actually the y-axis is not a time axis but a categorical one. This means I can't just use Math to add on further space to the axis. The only thing I could do is add an empty string as a label on both the first and last position of the label array. But this does not look ideal either.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake... good luck anway : /